# Embedding multiple instances of a flash component in a Flex application

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I have a flash application (pure AS, no Flex framework) that I'd like to embed inside of a flex application using SWFLoader.

Embedding one instance works well. However, when I try to embed multiple instances (each with a separate SwfLoader), there is really strange behavior that seems to be caused by clashes among the class definitions of the multiple instances. This flash application is written with a lot of singleton classes, so my guess is that these singletons are overriding each other and causing the weird behavior.

I tried loading the flash application into a child applicationdomain, but that doesn't seem to help much either. Has anyone faced this problem?

Comment: Can you try with two different applications? That way we can be sure if your singleton's are to be blamed or not?

Comment: When the two applications are loaded in child application domains, the singletons don't clash. It's only when they're loaded into the same application domain that they clash. Let me investigate further to find the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to load the SWF into its own application domain (not a child) to avoid name clashing.

There are three types of application domains:

```
var swfLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();

// child SWF adds its unique definitions to
// parent SWF; both SWFs share the same domain
// child SWFs definitions do not overwrite parents
loaderContext.applicationDomain = new ApplicationDomain(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);

// child SWF uses parent domain definitions
// if defined there, otherwise its own
loaderContext.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;

// child SWF domain is completely separate and
// each SWF uses its own definitions
loaderContext.applicationDomain = new ApplicationDomain();

// Load the swf file
swfLoader.load(new URLRequest("file.swf"), loaderContext);
```

I would suggest using the first method, as it will not overwrite definitions.